# Como, cuando y la funcionalidad de COLLATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, ordenamiento

Quería consultar cuando se usa `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` y cual seria su funcionalidad principal, ya que no entiendo muy bien esa función y la he visto que la utilizan en los `WHERE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Intercalaciones en SQL Server

El *collation* o *collate*, conocido en español como [intercalación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support), de acuerdo a la documentación es:

> Las intercalaciones de SQL Server proporcionan propiedades de distinción entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, acentos y reglas de ordenación para los datos. Las intercalaciones que se usan con tipos de datos de caracteres, como char y varchar, dictan la página de códigos y los caracteres correspondientes que se pueden representar para ese tipo de datos.

Esta intercalación aplica a varios niveles, por ejemplo hay una intercalación por defecto de la instancia de SQL Server, una por defecto de cada base de datos y, al final, cada columna de tipos de datos carácter, como `char`, `varchar` tiene su propia intercalación. Las columnas que se creen sin especificar una intercalación, se crean con la intercalación por defecto de la base de datos.

Las bases de datos que se creen sin especificar una intercalación, se crean con la intercalación por defecto de la instancia de base de datos.

Esta intercalación, en términos prácticos, define cuando se da una coincidencia al hacer una comparación de igualdad o de no igualdad, además del ordenamiento de un conjunto de resultados.

En el primer caso, vamos a crear una tabla con tres columnas con distintas intercalaciones y a insertarle algunos datos:

```
create table #prueba (
  id   int not null identity(1, 1)
, str1 varchar(100) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
, str2 varchar(100) collate Latin1_General_100_CI_AI
, str3 varchar(100) collate Latin1_General_100_CS_AS
);

insert into #prueba(str1, str2, str3)
values ('Hernández', 'HERNANDEZ', 'HERNÁNDEZ')
     , ('Hernandez', 'Hernández', 'HERNANDEZ')
     , ('HERNÁNDEZ', 'Hernandez', 'Hernández')
     , ('HERNANDEZ', 'HERNÁNDEZ', 'Hernandez')
;
```

### Comparaciones con cadenas constantes

Ahora, ejecutemos algunas consultas y veamos sus resultados:

```
select *
  from #Prueba
 where str1 = 'Hernández'
```

```
id   str1         str2         str3
---- ------------ ------------ -------------
1    Hernández    HERNANDEZ    HERNÁNDEZ
3    HERNÁNDEZ    Hernandez    Hernández

(2 rows affected)
```

```
select *
  from #Prueba
 where str2 = 'Hernández'
```

```
id   str1         str2         str3
---- ------------ ------------ -------------
1    Hernández    HERNANDEZ    HERNÁNDEZ
2    Hernandez    Hernández    HERNANDEZ
3    HERNÁNDEZ    Hernandez    Hernández
4    HERNANDEZ    HERNÁNDEZ    Hernandez

(4 rows affected)
```

```
select *
  from #Prueba
 where str3 = 'Hernández'
```

```
id   str1         str2         str3
---- ------------ ------------ -------------
3    HERNÁNDEZ    Hernandez    Hernández

(1 row affected)
```

Como puedes ver, una misma condición de igualdad, aplicada sobre las distintas columnas devuelve diferentes resultados, 2, 4, y 1 filas coinciden en cada ocasión con la cadena 'Hernández'.

### CI/CS AI/AS

Esto es porque algunas intercalaciones son sensibles o no a mayúsculas y minúsculas (CS=Case Sensitive o CI=Case Insensitive). En una intercalación *Case Insensitive*, `A` es igual a `a`, mientras en una *Case Sensitive* no lo son.

También algunas intercalaciones son sensibles a acentos. (AS=Accent Sensitive y AI=Accent Insensitive). En una intercalación *Accent Insensitive*, `á` es igual a `a`, mientras que en una *Accent Sensitive* no son iguales.

Tenemos todas las combinaciones posibles, CI_AI, CI_AS, CS_AI, CS_AS. En CI_AI, `á` es igual a `A`, en CS_AS `á` solamente es igual a si misma.

### Comparaciones entre columnas

Cuándo intentas comparar dos columnas que tienen diferente intercalación, SQL Server va a generar un error, en mi caso:

```
select *
  from #Prueba
 where str1 = str2;
```

Genera

```
Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 29
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_100_CI_AI" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.
```

Esto básicamente está diciendo que, al tener reglas diferentes para determinar la coincidencia en cada una de las cadenas, el motor es incapaz de decidir qué regla aplicar.

Para resolverlo, podemos indicar de manera explícita qué intercalación queremos que se aplique a cualquier columna con la sintaxis `columna collate nombre_intercalación`. Entonces, por ejemplo, podemos aplicar a una columna la intercalación de la otra:

```
select *
  from #Prueba
 where str1 collate Latin1_General_100_CI_AI = str2;
```

```
id   str1         str2         str3
---- ------------ ------------ -------------
1    Hernández    HERNANDEZ    HERNÁNDEZ
2    Hernandez    Hernández    HERNANDEZ
3    HERNÁNDEZ    Hernandez    Hernández
4    HERNANDEZ    HERNÁNDEZ    Hernandez

(4 rows affected)
```

O podríamos aplicar a ambas una intercalación diferente de la que tienen, siempre que a ambos lados de la igualdad apliquemos la misma:

```
select *
  from #Prueba
 where str1 collate Latin1_General_100_CS_AS = str2 collate Latin1_General_100_CS_AS;
```

```
id   str1         str2         str3
---- ------------ ------------ -------------
(0 rows affected)
```

### Ordenamiento

Finalmente, el ordenamiento, lo dejo de tarea al lector, esta respuesta es ya demasiado larga para el formato de StackOverflow, basta probar las diferentes sentencias:

```
select *
  from #Prueba
 order by str1;

select *
  from #Prueba
 order by str2;

select *
  from #Prueba
 order by str3;
```

## Qué intercalaciones están disponibles:

SQL Server viene con una gran cantidad de intercalaciones, útiles para diferentes regiones del mundo, idiomas y formas de uso. Puedes ver un listado de todas las intercalaciones disponibles en tu instancia con la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT name, description FROM sys.fn_helpcollations()
```

### Recomendación

Para las lenguas latinas en general, la recomendación es utilizar `Latin1_General_100*`, para español en particular, `Modern_Spanish*`

Comment: Solo agregaría que toda la instancia debería de tener la misma intercalación para evitar la necesidad de usar COLLATE. Pero es una excelente respuesta.

Comment: Luis, gracias por el comentario, me halaga viniendo de un experto en SQL Server. Sobre el _debería_, creo que es lo ideal, aunque hay ocasiones dónde, sin embargo, es necesario tener distintos collates, lo primero que me viene a la mente como uso legítimo es una tabla que tenga nombres o descripciones en múltiples idiomas, a los que aplica distinta intercalación. Claro que no falta quién termina teniendo campos con distintas intercalaciones por puro descuido y eso no debiera pasar, pero lo he visto muchas veces...

Comment: Tienes razón. En SQL Server no existen absolutos, pero las excepciones deben de tener buenas razones para aplicarlas.